# jSignature - generated value won't render

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsignature

I'm using the latest jSignature (https://github.com/brinley/jSignature), generating base30 signatures and saving them in a mysql database. This usually works great; on this occasion, though, the user input a signature, it saved, but the signature won't render. Instead, a very non-descript javascript error appears in the dev tools. I have a jsfiddle of it up here:

https://jsfiddle.net/evilpluto/onh3z3k0/

To activate it, I just pull from a hidden form field like so

`$(".signature_form").height("170px").jSignature("reset").jSignature("importData", 'data:'+ $(".hiddenSigDataForm").val());`

It just seems like the base30 that was generated is corrupt in some way, but I'm not sure why it would generate the javascript error. In the jfiddle I put a working button (loads fine) and then the base30 string that errors as the "non-working" button.

Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that the error that appears in the js console is: "TypeError: e is undefined", super non-helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, oops. The problem was not that jsignature magically couldn't render anymore. The problem was I stored the value in a varchar(255), and the base30 value was truncated to the point that it was unusable. My others worked because they were smaller.

Then I figured out that mysql now allows > 255 in varchars...this has been a very educational night.